# Extend Wifi via Intermediate 3g

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, raspberry-pi

This is what I currently have:
(Device1).....Wifi.....(Device2)

And this is what I need:
(Device1)...Wifi...(RaspberryPi1)...3g...(RaspberryPi2)...Wifi...(Device2)

The 2 Devices should not get to know that we have this setup between them. They should just be able to connect like normal Wifi.

Also, 3g providers in my country don't provide with public IP.

How can I make this setup? Please help!

**Edit:** Let's say Device1 is an access point with known SSID. So, after the setup, RaspberryPi1 should automatically cannect to Device1 and at the other end, RasberryPi2 should form an access point with the same SSID as Device1.

Although we want to use 3g on both the RaspberryPis but if there is no other option, we can use a wired internet connection with public IP on RaspberryPi2.

**Edit 2:** More specifically, I am using AR Drone 2.0. We need connect to its Wifi and its APIs are written in such a way that they connect to the IP Address of the Drone and exchange some data with it. Now, I wanted to remove any bounds on the range of my Drone and wanted to use 3g for that.

Comment: Can you describe the constraint better: "devices should not get to know we have the setup".   What do you mean by this?  And when you say "extend wifi" I am presuming you don't mean you want some how transmit wifi signals - you just want to create a VPN between the two networks right?

Comment: Will both Raspberry Pi's be using 3G ? Or will one or the other be using a service with a public IP address ?

Comment: Just setting the ssids the same will achieve what you have described in the edit.  Please consider expanding the question to include *why* you want to do this, it might help us understand what the actual problem you are trying to solve is.

Comment: I want the setup to take requests from Device2 and forward them to Device1 and listen to reply from Device1 and forward it to Device2. How is that as simple as you have written provided we don't even have  public IPs for RaspberryPis?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the ArDrone protocol, but I'm assuming it needs to be on the same Layer2 network for its discovery-protocol to work.

The first challenge is to have the Raspberry Pi's talk to each other. You already mention that you don't get public IP addresses, but can you connect directly from one Raspberry Pi to the (private) address of the other Raspberry pi? If this is not the case, you will need a "rendez-vouz point" that will allow both RPi's to communicate with it, and it will relay all massages to the other RPi.

Once you have your both Raspberry Pi's talking to each other, you need to connect the 2 ethernet segments to eachother. One way of doing this would be to set up a L2TP, for example using http://www.openl2tp.org/.